# Is there any Mac Application used for part-zooming a picture?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, accessibility

I found many screenshots for Mac App Store or iTunes App Store using pictures like this,
I want to find a Mac App can do this work.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is built in ML 10.8 with the accessibility feature zoom. Go to system preferences Accessibility, select zoom the last feature is zoom style select picture-in-picture. This will be a rectangle and follows your mouse any where on screen. You can use option command = (to enlarge) or - (to decrees) the text under the magnifying rectangle, if you have a keyboard with num pad you can use option command + or - for the same effect.

Answer (score -1):

It's called a Loupe tool.  You'll find it in a lot of different image editing programs. 
Both Photoshop and Aperture have Loupe tools built in.

Comment: Aren't those just for viewing the image, though?